# Saving data from one input form in one component and pre-populating another form with this data in a nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Hello to you bright minds!

I am not a senior React dev, thus confusion...

I have a SignUp.jsx page to which we get via a Navbar link. Signup.jsx has a nested component VerifyAxios.jsx inside of which there is a Formik form with a verify button that gathers client data (firstName, lastName, clientEmail, ) upon pressing verify this form sends data to a few server endpoints, then it is hidden (thus at this point it doesn't redirect yet, and thus here I loose an opportunity to do something with the form data I think...) and another form with only one input field is revealed to enter the verification code and then we press continue - here the redirect happens.

SignUp.jsx

```
// Render Prop
import React from 'react';

import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import { GirlWithPhone } from '../../assets';

import VerifyAxios from '../verifycode/VerifyAxios';

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const SignUp = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {/* DARK BAR UNDER MENU  */}
            <motion.div
                initial='hidden'
                whileInView='visible'
                viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.5 }}
                transition={{ duration: 1 }}
                variants={{
                    hidden: { opacity: 1, y: 30 },
                    visible: { opacity: 1, y: 0 },
                }}
            >
                <div className='w-full flex-row bg-underNavBar p-3'></div>
            </motion.div>
            {/* WRAPPER */}
            <div className='flex flex-wrap-reverse justify-center items-center px-10 py-20  bg-purple-100'>
                {/* IMAGE LEFT COLUMN */}
                <div className='lg:w-[50%] mx-6 my-10'>
                    <img src={GirlWithPhone} alt='Your Personal Number is Safe with Us' className='rounded-lg' />
                </div>
                {/* FORM RIGHT COLUMN  */}
                <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center mx-6 pt-4'>
                    <VerifyAxios />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default SignUp;
```

VerifyAxios.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import * as Yup from 'yup';
import axios from 'axios';

const pinRegExp = /^\d{5}$/;
const emailRule = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i;
const nameRule = /^[A-Za-z\s]{0,25}$/;
const mobileNumberRule = /^\d{11}$/;

const initialValues = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    clientEmail: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    verificationCode: '',
};

const resetForm = () => {
    console.log(values);
    resetForm({ values: '' });
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    firstName: Yup.string().min(2, 'Too Short!').max(25, 'Too Long!').matches(nameRule).required('First Name is required'),
    lastName: Yup.string().min(2, 'Too Short!').max(25, 'Too Long!').matches(nameRule).required('Last Name is required'),
    clientEmail: Yup.string().matches(emailRule, 'Verify Email Format').required('Email is required'),
    phoneNumber: Yup.string().matches(mobileNumberRule, 'Use 11 digits, Country Code plus Number. Example: 44325485786').required('Phone number is required'),
});

const verificationSchema = Yup.object({
    verificationCode: Yup.string().matches(pinRegExp, 'Verification Code must be 5 digits').required('Verification code is required'),
});

// START OF VERIFY FUNCTION
const VerifyAxios = () => {
    const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
    const [submitError, setSubmitError] = useState(null);
    const [sentCode, setSentCode] = useState(null);

    // GET COOKIES
    // const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies();

    // GET URL PARAMS AND UTMS
    // const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.pathname);

    // REDIRECT TO APPROPRIATE
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // PHONE NUMBER VERIFICATION
    const handlePhoneNumberSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
        try {
            // REQUEST PIN NUMBER
            const dataRequestPin = {
                imsi: 'HIDDEN',
                phoneNumber: values.phoneNumber,
            };

            // CREATE LEAD
            const dataCreateLead = {
                cusFirstName: values.firstName,
                cusLastName: values.lastName,
                cusEmail: values.clientEmail,
                phoneNumber: values.phoneNumber,
                // getParams: urlParams.getAll,
                // postParams: '',
                // cookies: cookies,
            };
            console.log(dataCreateLead);

            // SIM CODE VERIFICATION ENDPOINT
            const responseCode = await axios.post('http://ENDPOINT HIDDEN/requestSimCode', dataRequestPin);

            // CREATE LEAD - ADD USER TO THE CONXHUB PORTAL
            const responseLead = await axios.post('http://ENDPOINT HIDDEN/createLead', dataCreateLead);

            setSubmitting(false);

            // Log the entire response object
            // console.log('Response:', responseCode);

            if (responseCode.dataRequestPin && responseLead.dataCreateLead && responseCode.dataRequestPin.verifCode) {
                setVerificationCode(responseCode.dataRequestPin.verifCode);
                // console.log(`Response Data verifCode: ${responseCode.dataRequestPin.verifCode}`);
                setSubmitError(null);
                setSentCode(responseCode.dataRequestPin.verifCode);
                // console.log(setSentCode(responseCode.dataRequestPin.verifCode));
                initialValues.phoneNumber = values.phoneNumber;
            } else {
                console.log('verifCode is undefined');
            }
            // Hide phoneNumberForm
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberForm').classList.add('hidden');

            // Show verificationCodeForm
            document.getElementById('verificationCodeForm').classList.remove('hidden');
            document.getElementById('verificationCodeForm').classList.add('block');
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.responseCode) {
                // Response not in the 200 range
                setSubmitting(false);
                setVerificationCode('');
                setSubmitError(error.message);
                setSentCode(null);
                // console.log(error.responseCode.dataRequestPin);
                // console.log(error.responseCode.dataCreateUser);
                // console.log(error.responseCode.status);
                // console.log(error.responseCode.headers);
            } else {
                // No Response at all or 404 or something else occured
                console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
            }
        }
        // Reset Client Input form
        resetForm({ values: '' });
    };

    const handleVerificationCodeSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
        // Access the firstName, lastName, and userEmail values
        // const { firstName, lastName, clientEmail } = carryUserData;
        try {
            const data = {
                verifCode: values.verificationCode,
            };

            const response = await axios.post('http://ENDPOINT HIDDEN/verifySimCode', data);

            // console.log('This is the PIN number: ', value.verificationCode);
            console.log('Server response is:', response.status);
            // The purpose of setSubmitting is to manage the submit button state while the form is being submitted. By setting the state to false, the submit button is re-enabled after the submission is complete.
            setSubmitting(false);
            // setSubmitError is used to manage any submission errors that may occur while the form is being submitted. By setting the state to null, any previously set error state is cleared, and the component is reset to its initial state.
            setSubmitError(null);

            if (response.status === 200) {
                alert('Success, your number is verified');
                console.log('The status is 200');
                setSubmitError(null);
                setVerificationCode('');
                resetForm();
                // REDIRECT TO STRIPE CHECKOUT IF VERIFICATION CODE IS ACCEPTED
                navigate('/signup/subscribe');
            } else {
                alert('Invalid Verification Code');
                console.log('There was an error');
                setSubmitError('Verification Failed');
                setVerificationCode('');
                resetForm();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setSubmitting(false);
            setSubmitError(error.message);
            alert('Wrong phone number or verification code');
        }
        // Reset Client Input form
        resetForm({ values: '' });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='text-buttonColor text-2xl lg:text-3xl pb-4'>Create your VIP Experience</h1>
            <h3 className='text-buttonColor text-xl lg:text-xl pb-4'>Lets start with verifying your phone number</h3>
            {submitError && <div className='error-message'>{submitError}</div>}

            <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={handlePhoneNumberSubmit}>
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form id='phoneNumberForm' className='block flex flex-col max-w-full gap-4 '>
                        <div className='flex flex-col gap-6'>
                            {/* FIRST NAME  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='firstName'>
                                    First Name:
                                </label>
                                <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='firstName' name='firstName' type='text' />
                                <ErrorMessage name='firstName' />
                            </div>
                            {/* LAST NAME  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='lastName'>
                                    Last Name:
                                </label>
                                <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='lastName' name='lastName' type='text' />
                                <ErrorMessage name='lastName' />
                            </div>
                            {/* EMAIL  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='clientEmail'>
                                    Email:
                                </label>
                                <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='clientEmail' name='clientEmail' type='clientEmail' />
                                <ErrorMessage name='clientEmail' />
                            </div>
                            {/* MOBILE NUMBER  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='phoneNumber'>
                                    Enter Your Mobile Number Including Country Code :
                                </label>
                                <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='phoneNumber' name='phoneNumber' type='tel' />
                                <ErrorMessage name='phoneNumber' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button className='bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 text-white font-semibold h-10 rounded-md mt-4' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                            {isSubmitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Verify your Mobile Number'}
                        </button>
                        <div>
                            <h4 className='text-base text-buttonColor'>You will receive an SMS with a verification code to validate next...</h4>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>

            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={verificationSchema}
                onSubmit={handleVerificationCodeSubmit} // Add this line
            >
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form id='verificationCodeForm' className=' hidden flex justify-center items-center flex-col max-w-full gap-2 mt-10 '>
                        <div className='flex flex-col gap-4'>
                            <label className='text-buttonColor text-2xl text-center' htmlFor='verificationCode'>
                                Verification Code:
                            </label>
                            <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='verificationCode' name='verificationCode' type='text' />
                            <ErrorMessage name='verificationCode' />

                            <button className='bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 h-10 rounded-md mt-2 text-white font-semibold' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                                {isSubmitting ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit'}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VerifyAxios;
```

The page redirects to a SubscriptionPlan.jsx page with a nested component PaymentForm.jsx inside of which I have Stripe input fields to gather data/create Stripe customer. I need to pre-populate the Stripe form with the firstName, lastName, clientEmail, phoneNumber from the data entered into the form in VerifyAxios.jsx. I am trying to use React Context, but don't have clear direction where to start with it as I don't have the grasp on createContext().

SubscriptionPlan.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { SingleHeart } from '../../assets';

import { useFormValues } from '../verifycode/useFormValues';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('STRIPE KEY');

const SubscriptionPlan = () => {
    const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(null);
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);

// Stripe Related Code Hidden

                <section id='stripePayment' className='w-full p-4 lg:w-1/2 lg:p-10 pt-10 shadow-xl'>
                    {subscription ? (
                        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                            <PaymentForm subscription={subscription} product={product} />
                        </Elements>
                    ) : (
                        <div>Loading plan details...</div>
                    )}
                </section>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default SubscriptionPlan;
```

PaymentForm.jsx

```
import { PaymentElement, CardElement, Elements, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import axios from 'axios';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const emailRule = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i;
const nameRule = /^[A-Za-z\s]{0,50}$/;

const PaymentForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const initialValues = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
    };

    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
        // name: Yup.string().min(2, 'Too Short!').max(50, 'Too Long!').matches(nameRule).required('Name is required'),
        name: Yup.string().min(2, 'Too Short!').max(50, 'Too Long!').matches(nameRule),
        // email: Yup.string().matches(emailRule, 'Verify Email Format').required('Email is required'),
        email: Yup.string().matches(emailRule, 'Verify Email Format'),
    });

    // REDIRECT TO THE CONFIRMATION PAGE
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // CHECK IF CUSTOMER ALREADY EXISTS
    const checkExistingClient = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1447/check-existing-client', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                }),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to check existing client');
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            if (data.clientExists) {
                throw new Error('Client is already subscribed');
            }

            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        }
    };

    // CREATE NEW CUSTOMER SUBSCRIPTION
    const createSubscription = async () => {
        try {
            // CHECKING IF CUSTOMER ALREADY SIBSCRIBED
            const isExistingClient = await checkExistingClient();

            if (!isExistingClient) {
                return;
            }

            // CREATE STRIPE PAYMENT METHOD
            const paymentMethod = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: elements.getElement('card'),
            });

            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1447/create-subscription', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    paymentMethod: paymentMethod.paymentMethod.id,
                }),
            });
            if (!response.ok) return alert('Payment unsuccessful! Response not ok at paymentform.jsx line 42');

            const data = await response.json();

            const confirm = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.clientSecret);
            if (confirm.error) {
                return alert('Payment unsuccessful! confirm.error at paymentform.jsx line 45');
            }
            alert('Payment successful! Subscription is active');

            // CREATE CUSTOMER
            const dataCreateUser = {
                cusFirstName: values.firstName,
                cusLastName: values.lastName,
                cusEmail: values.clientEmail,
                cusSimNumber: values.phoneNumber,
                cusCountryISO3: '',
                leadId: '',
            };
            console.log(dataCreateUser);

            // SIM CODE VERIFICATION ENDPOINT
            const responseCode = await axios.post('http://ENDPOINT HIDDEN/createUser', dataCreateUser);

            // REDIRECT TO STRIPE CONFIRMATION PAGE
            navigate('/signup/confirmation');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert('Payment failed, ' + error.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h1 className='text-4xl pb-10 text-buttonColor font-semibold'>Payment Form</h1>

            <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={createSubscription}>
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form id='stripeCustomer' className='block flex flex-col max-w-full gap-4 '>
                        <div className='flex flex-col gap-6'>
                            {/* FIRST NAME  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='firstName'>
                                    First Name:
                                </label>
                                <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='firstName' name='firstName' type='text' />
                                <ErrorMessage name='firstName' />
                            </div>
                            {/* LAST NAME  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='lastName'>
                                    Last Name:
                                </label>
                                <Field autoComplete='off' className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2' id='lastName' name='lastName' type='text' />
                                <ErrorMessage name='lastName' />
                            </div>
                            {/* EMAIL  */}
                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='email'>
                                    Email:{''}
                                </label>
                                <Field
                                    autoComplete='off'
                                    className='bg-purple-200 h-10 w-60 min-w-full rounded-md p-2'
                                    id='email'
                                    name='email'
                                    type='email'
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                />
                                <ErrorMessage name='email' />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label className='text-buttonColor' htmlFor='cardElement'>
                                Enter Your Card Number:{''}
                            </label>
                            {/* <PaymentElement className='bg-purple-200 p-2 rounded-md' id='cardElement' /> */}
                            <CardElement id='cardElement' className='bg-purple-200 p-2 h-10 rounded-md' />
                        </div>
                        <button className='bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 text-white font-semibold h-10 rounded-md mt-4' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                            {isSubmitting ? 'Subscribing...' : 'Subscribe'}
                        </button>
                        <div>
                            <h5 className='text-xs text-center text-buttonColor lg:px-20'>
                                By confirming your subscription, you allow VIP Safety First to charge your card for this payment and future payments in accordance with their terms. You can always
                                cancel your subscription.
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex justify-center text-xl text-buttonColor'>
                            <h5 className='text-sm text-buttonColor'>Powered by Stripe</h5>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </>
    );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

So far what I have found is that I can create a separate file named FormDataContext.js and import it into the Signup.jsx, but after that I'm confused...

Is this even correct approach or is there an easier way?

Thank you tribe!!

FormDataContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const FormDataContext = createContext();

export const FormDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

    const setVerifyFormData = (data) => {
        setFormData(data);
    };

    return <FormDataContext.Provider value={{ formData, setVerifyFormData }}>{children}</FormDataContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).